# why does paxos proposalId need to be unique

Tags: paxos

could anyone tell me why the proposal Id needs to be unique in Paxos?
I think the reason why this the proposalId needs to be unique is that we need to use it to reject the old proposal and sort the max vote.  So if we make the phase one: acceptor only accepts the proposal greater than the promisedId and it is incremental, it still can guarantee the consistency.

We assume proposer A makes a proposal (proposalId x, value y) to acceptors, then he got the majority reply with approval,  another proposer B with the same proposal id(x) issue a proposal request, this proposer B will be rejected, right? And eventually, we still can reach consistency, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that the proof of correctness depends on numbers being unique to each node at each round.

An intuitive answer is as follows:

If proposal numbers are not unique between nodes in the cluster you could have two nodes propose different values for the same number. Under arbitrary message loss some nodes may accept one value and some the other. A potential new leader will ask all nodes their highest accepted value. It will then get back responses that are different values for the same number. It cannot then disambiguate and decide which value is the one to choose next to bring the cluster to consistency. Using unique numbers ensures that each value has a unique number in each round. That ensures that a new leader can correctly pick the highest accepted value.

Contrived Scenario:

A five node cluster with node `A` the leader. The network goes haywire. Node `B` thinks it needs to lead as it suspects node `A` is dead due to lost messages. Node `B` proposes the same number last used by `A`. Nodes `A` and `B` are actually both up and attempt to transmit a different value to the other nodes. The power fails and all nodes go dark and some but not all messages got through as the network got disrupted due to the rolling power failure.

Next the power comes back on but nodes `A` and `E` remain dead. Nodes `B`, `C` and `D` can form a quorum. Node `C` proposes a fresh high number and gets back two different values for the highest accepted value. One originates from `A` and the other from `B`. It now has to choose between them. Which value is guaranteed to bring the cluster to the correct consistency?

Imagine that in the surviving quorum only one node has the `A` value but two nodes have the `B` value. So let's say we guess `B`s value but that could be wrong. Dead nodes `A` and `E` may have `A`s value. Node `A` happened to see a majority of responses for its value prior to the power failure as it's message happened to get through to two other nodes. The value was a payment and it sent the money out of the company when it saw a majority response. Yet the surviving quorum decided that `A`s value never happened and bring the cluster to consistency with `B`s value.

The Fix:

All you need to do is uniquely number each node and encode the node unique number into the least significant bits of the ballot numbers. Then each node uses numbers unique to it and can easily generate a new number just higher than the last highest number used within the cluster. If we did that only one value would be the highest accepted at any round.

Any new leader with a majority will then see the highest value used by the last leader if that last leader got a majority response. The new leader won't then contradict the last leader it will collaborate. The new leader doesn't need to know whether the dead leader actually saw a majority response and acted upon it. Rather it makes the conservative choice and assumes it may have and acts appropriately.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply ,consider the below condition ,if we make the paxos condition be more strict ,the acceptor only accept the proposal number greater than what it received before ,rather than accept the proposal with a condition equals or greater than what it received,then the proposal Id does not have to be unique

Comment: No. Consider that in the scenario each node only ever sees one proposal message and one value so has no reason not to make a promise. The scenario of a new leader not being able to disambiguate which value to fix remains.

Comment: Paxos itself is mechanically very simple. What is complex is how many states any three or five nodes can get into. With pencil and paper you can start to figure out what sorts of scenarios are possible under message loss, crashes, IO stalls, arbitrary network partitions. What's interesting is that Paxos exchanges very few messages to be correct. The moment you attempt to change it or optimise it you start to make invalid assumptions about possibly states of the system or require more messages or additional messages to try to correct the system.

Comment: An arbitrary partition means messages on any route between any two nodes might fail in one or both directions. Why? Incorrect firewall rules due to human error. IO stall means VM or disk might freeze and resume or operators might accidently suspended. During 2015 I am aware of two companies using entirely different technologies (windows vs Linux) that had problems due to servers stalling then resuming due to different virtualisation software overloading. Also network saturation or packet corruption to lose messages at random. Given all the things that can go on wrong many states are possible.

Comment: The only assumptions of Paxos is that a node doesn't forget a promise nor forget the highest accepted value. File systems buffer and lazy sync to disk so normal software such as java even after calling flush OS will lazy sync to disk. If process crashes you can forget promise or value as not on disk. You have to call file `sync()` which is not an api developers are typically aware of to force OS to sync disk. Google flush v sync to see difference. The sync is slow but required for Paxos assumptions so throughput of Paxos is lower than unsafe techniques

Comment: I edited the answer to highlight that arbitrary message loss is genuine problem in any distributed system.

Comment: So, when the proposer generates a proposal id, the proposal id is guarnteed to be unique among all proposers?  Say, I make up a `generateProposalId()` method which demands that the last few bits of a proposal id is always the predefined Proposer id and the proposal id also needs to be greater than max{known been voted proposal ids}. I think this makes the proposal id unique.  Or do I misunderstand something? Especially the Proposer id thing. I do not feel very confident about it.   thx.

Comment: Oh, I missed the last part of the answer on my first read. So it is what I think it is? But how can I assure the uniqueness of the `unique_number` that every  Proposer is holding? What's the common practice?

Comment: the common practice is to use paxos itself to allocate a unique number per node. then you encode the unique number of the node into the least significant bits of the paxos number. so you might reserve the lowest 8 bits for the node numbers (allowing you to replace many node many times over the life of the system allocating each replacement node a unique number). then the rest of the bits are regular counter that you increment. as no machine uses the same 16 bits all your numbers are unique.

Comment: @du369 here is a ballot number in scala https://github.com/trex-paxos/trex/blob/1927111c2aa713ac9fab94778482f1512fd5b169/library/src/main/scala/com/github/trex_paxos/library/PaxosProtocol.scala#L57 rather than encoding the two values in a single number that uses a compound type to represent a ballot number made of two parts and defines operators such as "<", "<=" etc for comparing two numbers. if you were using a lower level language like C you might do bit wise operations to pack the two components into a single `ulong` 64bit type.

Comment: "If proposal numbers are not unique between nodes in the cluster you could have two nodes propose different values for the same number.", I think this is not the case. Phase 1a: Prepare, If two nodes prepare with the same number, only one of them will get quorum promised, then only one node can invoke Phase 2a with that number. Never happen two nodes propose diff vals for same number, they just prepare for same number, and only one succeed.

Comment: @ideawu the numbers are the only discriminator for the algorithm. imagine if you were using a database table to track the algorithm (which is a silly idea it is just a thought experiment). what should the "primary key" of the "proposals table" be? if you had a "bug" in your logic where two different programs could overwrite each others rows in the table you would break. you could fix this by making the primary key of the table the combination of "app Id" and "app counter". then you would not have the bug. obviously paxos doesn't have a database table but needs "unique ids" to descrimate.

Answer (score 4):

There is an additional detail that may be worth pointing out and is touched upon by @ideawu in the comment thread on @simbo1905's answer. My answer given below may have been more appropriate as a comment on that thread but I don't have the required Stack Overflow reputation to post comments.

In the classic description of Paxos (e.g. [*Paxos Made Simple*](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/paxos-simple.pdf)), it is indeed required that ballot numbers/ids are unique to each proposer i.e. no two proposers can propose a value in the same ballot and each proposer cannot reuse ballot numbers for different proposals. My understanding is that this is simply to guarantee that at most one value is ever proposed for a given ballot.

As @simbo1905 points out, one way to ensure unique ballot numbers across proposals is by pre-allocating a disjoint set of ballot ids to each proposer. That is not the only way to achieve ballot uniqueness, though. If acceptors require that the ballot numbers of prepare (Phase 1a) messages they respond to are *strictly greater* than the ballot number of their latest promise, then this ensures that proposers will never conflict on a given ballot number, even if different proposers try to use the same ballot number for different proposals. The quorum overlap property ensures this, and it is a fact pointed out in Heidi Howard's technical report [*Distributed Consensus Revised*](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-935.pdf), where, in Section 3.9, she notes (using the term "epoch" instead of "ballot"):

> It has long been known that Classic Paxos does not require that epochs
> are unique if acceptors require that a proposer’s epochs be strictly
> greater than the last promised proposal. This means that at most one
> proposer will reach phase two for a given epoch, since reaching phase
> two requires a proposer to have already reached majority agreement for
> phase one, thus guaranteeing uniqueness.

This supports the idea proposed in the comment above by @ideawu. So, if we ensure this "strictly greater than" behavior for acceptors, ballot number uniqueness shouldn't be externally required i.e. the protocol will enforce it automatically.

Alternatively, if we allow acceptors to respond to prepare messages that have ballot numbers *greater than or equal* to their latest promised ballot, then uniqueness of ballot numbers for proposals is, indeed, not automatically guaranteed. This fact is, presumably, the original motivation for Paxos requiring global ballot number uniqueness. We can fix this, however, by modifying the protocol slightly. We can add an extra piece of state on each acceptor that stores the identity of the proposer it responded to for its latest promised ballot. If it receives a prepare request from a different proposer for the same ballot, it can reject it. Howard gives a precise example of this in the referenced paper section. This is also the approach taken, for example, in the Raft consensus protocol, where it is implemented using the *[votedFor](https://github.com/ongardie/raft.tla/blob/974fff7236545912c035ff8041582864449d0ffe/raft.tla#L53-L55)* variable maintained on each server.

You can see a more formal demonstration of the concepts outlined above in [this TLA+ specification](https://github.com/will62794/mypaxos/blob/62e47c0024bd843ad4954289833a21b2015a8b8e/Paxos.tla), which extends [one of Lamport's Paxos specifications](https://github.com/tlaplus/Examples/blob/cb1c424fd5ded07285b586fad272dbbbaf821ec7/specifications/Paxos/Paxos.tla) to add an explicit notion of proposers. Note that nothing in the specification ensures that different proposers choose ballot numbers from disjoint sets. Here is [an error trace](https://github.com/will62794/mypaxos/blob/62e47c0024bd843ad4954289833a21b2015a8b8e/gte_error_trace.txt) (counterexample) that is produced when using the "[greater than or equal to](https://github.com/will62794/mypaxos/blob/62e47c0024bd843ad4954289833a21b2015a8b8e/Paxos.tla#L107-L108)" condition and model checking the safety property that only a single value is chosen. When using the "[strictly greater than](https://github.com/will62794/mypaxos/blob/62e47c0024bd843ad4954289833a21b2015a8b8e/Paxos.tla#L105-L106)" condition, the model checker terminated without error on a model where the `Proposer` set is defined as `{p1,p2}` (two proposers) and `Nat` (which determines the set of possible ballots) is overridden to be `{1,2,3}`. That is by no means a proof of safety, but it gives a bit of extra confidence that the reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is actually incorrect - there is no requirement for a round number to be unique across nodes. The only requirement is "Each proposal is uniquely numbered for a given Proposer" and "The number n must be greater than any number used in any of the previous Prepare messages by this Proposer." - these are quotes from wikipedia - in spirit, this is the same requirement.

Let me explain why there is no global uniqueness requirement by an example (and address this argument from the originally accepted answer "It[Leader] will then get back responses that are different values for the same number.").

Let's say we have a system with two proposers and three accepters(and few learners):

1. Both proposers sent PREPARE(1) - same number - to all acceptors.
2. Based on paxos rules, only one of proposers will get the majority of PROMISE messages - this is based on the rule that acceptor promises if PREPARE has number strongly greater than any other previously seen by the acceptor.
3. Now we are in a state where one proposer has two (or three) PROMISES for N=1 and the other proposer has one (or zero) PROMISE with N = 1.
4. Only first proposer may issue ACCEPT(1, V) as it got majority. The other proposer does not have the majority of PROMISES and has to retry with a larger N.
5. After the other proposer retries, it will use N larger than any other it saw before - hence it will try with N=2
6. From now on, it's all works the same way - proposer PREPARES and if get majority of PROMISE for its N, then the proposer issues ACCEPT(N, VALUE_ACCORDING_TO_PROTOCOL)

The key understanding for paxos is there is no way to have two ACCEPT(N, V) messages being sent where same N will have different V, hence there is no issue that two proposer use the same N.

As for initiating every node with some unique ID - that's ok; will it improve the performance - it's a big question and I haven't see a formal proof for that yet.